# If connecting an ammeter in parallel will cause short circuit, why won't connecting it in series does?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, short-circuits

short circuit will happen when there is nearly no resistance in a wire, and when a high current almost infinite flowing through the wire, causing high temperature.

But connected in series, an ammeter, at least the section it composes in the whole circuit, also has low resistance. So wouldn't a high/ infinite current also occur producing short circuit?

Comment: I honestly don't understand the reasoning here.  The ammeter appears as a wire to the rest of the circuit.  Wires are used to connect circuit elements.  For example, consider a simple circuit consisting of a light bulb connected to a battery with two wires; no infinite current.  Now, replace one of the wires with an ammeter - the ammeter is in series with the light bulb but, to the rest of the circuit, the ammeter is essentially a wire just as before, i.e., the current through the bulb is the same (ideally) as when there was just a wire; no infinite current.

Answer (score 3):

An ammeter measures current; to measure the current directly it must flow through the ammeter. The typical ammeter is designed to do this by being added into your circuit in series, at the point you need to know the current.

In order not to disturb the circuit, this is designed with a low resistance so that the voltage drop is minimal. The same current flows through each portion of a series branch of a circuit.

OTOH, the typical voltmeter is connected in parallel, and has a high impedance; in a parallel connection the voltages are the same for each of the parallel branches, and the high impedance means that minimal current will flow through this additional branch, leaving the rest of the circuit unaffected.

So what happens if the ammeter setting is hooked up in parallel? With a very low resistance in the ammeter, all of the available current will flow through the ammeter, possibly damaging it. And if it is not damaged, it won't give a typical reading for the circuit being tested, because the circuit has been altered.

What happens if the voltmeter setting is hooked up in series?  Then the high impedance of the voltmeter will result in a significant voltage drop in that part of the circuit. Once again, the value being shown is not typical of the actual circuit.

Comment: A diagram would make this pretty obvious :)

Comment: But doesn't in series all the available current also flow through the ammeter?

Answer (score 2):

An ammeter has very low resistance. When you put it in series, you put its (low) resistance **in series** with the rest of the circuitry. The current that flows will be determined by the **total** resistance, i.e. the sum of the ammeter and the rest of the circuit. As the ammeter's resistance is very low, the total current will be very similar to the current that would flow without the ammeter.

Let's take an example. Say the voltage ($V$) is 10V, the ammeter's resistance is $0.1\Omega$ and the rest of the circuit has a resistance of $100\Omega$. If we connect the circuit without the ammeter we get a current of $0.1A$, because$$A=10V/100\Omega=0.1A$$

If we connect the ammeter in series, the resistance becomes $R=0.1+100=100.1\Omega$, and the current is $$A=10V/100.1\Omega=0.0999A$$In orther words, almost no change.

If, on the other hand, we put the ammeter in parallel with the load, the total resistance would become$$R=0.1*100/(0.1+100)=10/100.1=0.0999$$
That would create the following current:$$A=10V/0.0999\Omega=100.1A$$

The current is now much **larger**, because the parallel connected ammeter has drastically reduced the resistance in the circuit.

Comment: Will short circuit happen if say voltage rise (battery) is more than voltage drop (resistor)?

Comment: There is only a voltage drop across a resistor when there is current flowing through it. It is the current that causes the voltage drop, so the voltage drop can never be greater than the battery voltage. Hence your short circuit cannot happen.